# How does GitVersion's +semver command work?

Tags: git, git-flow, gitversion

I am trying to bump my patch version number with [GitVersion](https://gitversion.net/docs/)'s [`+semver:patch`](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/v3.6.5/more-info/version-increments#commit-messages) command, but it's not working the way I expect.

I have a tag '2.2.0' on my **master** branch.  And I have made the following commits on my **develop** branch:

```
b5d9f141  (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) +semver:patch
75122489  Added unit test. +semver:patch
3b4e7eef  (tag: 2.2.0, origin/master, master) Merge branch 'release/2.2.0'
```

I am following [GitFlow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html).  After the two recent commits, I would expect my version to be reported as 2.3.2, but GitVersion is still reporting it as 2.3.0.

> "MajorMinorPatch":"2.3.0"

How does `+semver` work, and is there any way to bump the active version number with only commit messages the way I'm intending (ie. without manual tagging)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitVersion works by

1. Finding the latest "base version," and then
2. Finding the most significant increment (ie. major, minor, patch).

In my case, the base version was taken from the most recent tag, 2.2.0.  My `+semver:patch` messages are considered as part of (2), but by default the develop branch is configured to increment the minor version:

```js
branches:
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
    increment: Minor
```

GitVersion does not, by default, "stack" increments — it simply takes the single most significant increment and applies it to the base version.  Some of the relevant code from [`IncrementStrategyFinder`](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/blob/master/src/GitVersionCore/VersionCalculation/IncrementStrategyFinder.cs#L26) is:

```cs
// cap the commit message severity to minor for alpha versions
if (baseVersion.SemanticVersion < new SemanticVersion(1) && commitMessageIncrement > VersionField.Minor)
{
    commitMessageIncrement = VersionField.Minor;
}

// don't increment for less than the branch config increment, if the absence of commit messages would have
// still resulted in an increment of configuration.Increment
if (baseVersion.ShouldIncrement && commitMessageIncrement < defaultIncrement)
{
    return defaultIncrement;
}
```

Since the develop branch already increments the base version by one minor version (ie. to 2.3.0), my patch version increment instructions are ignored.